# What is the correct term for "co-covering" designs

Tags: terminology, combinatorial-designs

An (n, k, l) *covering design* is a family of k-subsets of an n-element set such that every l-subset **is contained** in at least one of them. Now, what is the correct term for a family of k-subsets such that every l-subset **contains** one.

Comment: It's the complement of an n-k,n-l covering design.

Comment: That's right, although I suspect the OP knows this already.  Regarding naming, I think co-covering is not a bad term.  But design theory already has a proliferation of special terms, so it's maybe best to complement parameters as stated above.

Answer (score 1):

It's called Turán system.

See:
[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turán_number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tur%C3%A1n_number)

Answer (score 0):

You may be thinking of [Packing Designs](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/(SICI)1520-6610(1998)6:4%3C245::AID-JCD3%3E3.0.CO;2-F/abstract). They solve the problem of the largest set of $k$-sets none of which contain the same $l$-set.

Answer (score 0):

I'd call the *co-coverings* -- ***inscriptions***.

Answer (score 0):

In topology or set theory or in the Birkhoff lattice theory with $0$ and $1$, where *covering* means a collection such that the union is the total space (or total set or 1), the dual notion is a collection with the empty intersection (or $0$). Years ago I have introduced for such a dual notion the name ***ver***.

Perhaps, in the situation as above, perhaps name ***ver*** is still optimal, despite the overloading it.

Thus, after all, the name should be:

$$\mathbf{ver}$$

Simple.

Comment: It goes without saying that the dual to ***ver*** is ***cover***.